# removing specific domain address in a string

Tags: python, regex

```
str1 = "obul@ongoose.com|bharat@ongoose.com|rbasani@ongoose.com|srinu@gmail.com|"
```

now i need to convert above string  to `str2 = srinu@gmail.com|` by removing all `ongoose.com|` using regex in python or anyother way in python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Using regex**

```
>>> import re
>>> str1 = "obul@ongoose.com|bharat@ongoose.com|rbasani@ongoose.com|srinu@gmail.com|"
>>> re.sub(r'(^|\|)[^@]*?@ongoose.com', '', str1).lstrip('!')
'srinu@gmail.com|'
```

**Without regex**

```
>>> '|'.join([m for m in str1.split("|") if not m.endswith('@ongoose.com')])
'srinu@gmail.com|'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str.split` with negative indexing.

**Ex:**

```
str1 = "obul@ongoose.com|bharat@ongoose.com|rbasani@ongoose.com|srinu@gmail.com|"
print(str1.split("|")[-2])
```

**Output:**

```
srinu@gmail.com
```

*Or if the position of the string is dynamic.* You can use `str.endswith`

```
str1 = "obul@ongoose.com|bharat@ongoose.com|rbasani@ongoose.com|srinu@gmail.com|"
for i in str1.split("|"):
    if not i.endswith("ongoose.com"):
        print(i)
```

Comment: what if @gmail.com is in the middle of the string

Comment: You use the second approach